# How to find if the first character of last word in a NSString value is Ampersand using NSRegularExpression?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I would like to find if the first letter of last word starts with Ampersand in a NSString value using NSRegularExpression. 
I used the following expression, but it shows the last word matching even if the the ampersand  is anywhere in the last word. 
Please advice me that how can i achieve it. 
Thank you.

```
        BOOL flagSymbolFound = NO; 
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[&]\\b\\w*$" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error]; 
if(!error) { 
    NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:stringValue options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [stringValue length])];
          if(numberOfMatches > 0) 
              flagSymbolFound = YES; 
          else 
              flagSymbolFound = NO; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `"\\s[&]\\w+$"` pattern. It should match space-separated words, e.g. `foo &bar`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the "^" anchor to the beginning of your regex:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^[&]\\b\\w*$" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
```

Comment: Yes Ennuikiller, it is not working for me too. Do you have any other ideas? Thank you.